# BakkesMod winsock2 recv Crash

Tags: c++, plugins, winsock, recv

C++ BakkesMod Plugin using winsock2.h && Ws2tcpip.h && bakkesmod SDK (requires x64 Release builds only)

Problem: Crashes on recv(). Try-Catch doesn't stop it, threading doesn't stop it, all checks show it should work fine. Send works fine, and while I might be able to create a send-only ping, there are additional features I would like to use that require receiving small requests from the server.

Initialized Variables of Note:

```
// Socket.private
int sock;
std::thread* reader;
// Socket.public
std::function<void(void)> onConnect;
std::function<void(void)> onDisconnect;
std::function<void(std::string)> onMessageReceived;
std::function<void(ErrorType, std::string)> onError;

// Relevant Function(s)
int Socket::Connect(int tries) {
    if (tries <= 0)
        return -1;

    if (ConnectionState == 1)
        Disconnect();
    ConnectionState = 0;
    
    if (onError != NULL)
        onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Connecting...");
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        if (onError != NULL)
            onError(ErrorType::CREATE_FAILED, "Discord: Could not Create Socket");

        if (onDisconnect != NULL)
            onDisconnect();

        return Connect(tries - 1);
    }
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(this->Port);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, this->Address.c_str(), &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        if (onError != NULL)
            onError(ErrorType::BIND_FAILED, "Discord: Could not Bind Socket");

        if (onDisconnect != NULL)
            onDisconnect();

        return Connect(tries - 1);
    }
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        if (onError != NULL)
            onError(ErrorType::CONNECT_FAILED, "Discord: Could not Connect");

        if (onDisconnect != NULL)
            onDisconnect();

        return Connect(tries - 1);;
    }

    ConnectionState = 1;
    
    if (onError != NULL)
        onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Authenticating...");
    Send("AUTH " + this->AuthCode, 1);

    if (onConnect != NULL)
        onConnect();

    std::thread thread_obj([this] { this->Read(); });
    this->reader = &thread_obj;

    return 1;
}
```

Read Call:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4700 )
void Socket::Read() {
    if (onError != NULL)
        onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Receive Thread Started");
    int len = 0;
    // Tried {0} to solve warning 4700, also left uninitialized with same result
    char* msg = { 0 };
    int bytesreceived = 0;
    while (ConnectionState == 1) {
        do {
            char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
            int buflen = MAX_BUFFER;
            if (onError != NULL)
                onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Receiving...");
            try {
                // *CRASH LINE*
                len = recv(this->sock, buffer, buflen, 0);
            }
            catch (int e) {
                if (onError != NULL)
                    onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Receive Error (" + std::to_string(e) + ")");
            }

            if (onError != NULL)
                onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Received " + std::to_string(len) + " bytes");
            if (len > 0) {
                // Concatenate Buffer
            }
            if (onError != NULL)
                onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Buffered " + std::to_string(bytesreceived) + " bytes");
            // Parse for Command(s)
    }
    if (bytesreceived > 0) {
        if (onError != NULL)
            onError(ErrorType::NOT_CONNECTED, "Discord: Receive Closed with Data");
    }
    if (onError != NULL)
        onError(ErrorType::DEBUG, "Discord: Receive Thread Ended");
}
```

Debug Output:

```
[17:09:46] [bakkesmod] [class plg::FoxsLeaderboard] Discord: AutoConnecting
[17:09:46] [bakkesmod] [class plg::FoxsLeaderboard] Discord: Connecting...
[17:09:46] [bakkesmod] [class plg::FoxsLeaderboard] Discord: Authenticating...
[17:09:46] [bakkesmod] [class plg::FoxsLeaderboard] Discord Connected
[17:09:46] [bakkesmod] [class plg::FoxsLeaderboard] Discord: Receive Thread Started
[17:09:46] [bakkesmod] [class plg::FoxsLeaderboard] Discord: Receiving...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `recv`.

```
std::thread thread_obj([this] { this->Read(); });
this->reader = &thread_obj;

return 1;
```

This constructs a `std::thread` object, creating a new execution thread.

Afterwards, this function immediately `return`s.

Returning from the function destroys all objects in automatic scope. Including this `std::thread` object. It gets destroyed just like any other local variable.

Destroying a `std::thread` that has a non-detached execution thread results in `std::terminate` getting called, terminating the entire program.

Also, note that your `reader` pointer is a dangling pointer also, pointing to a destroyed object, after the function returns.

Comment: Originally, I had intended to store the thread directly to reader, but it wouldn't let me handle it like that. I believe I need a different thread management system for c++. However, this shouldn't be causing the crash on recv. The crash still occurs when done serially with adjustments to the Read function to return a value when received.

Comment: This is a guaranteed crash. Whether in `recv`, or somewhere else. Probably it just so happens, on your specific operating system, that the parent execution thread gets around to `std::terminate()` nearly always at the same time as the new thread enter `recv`. Basically, once [demons start flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) you can no longer expect any specific results. You will need to fix how this thread is getting created.

Comment: So, I guess the question boils down to, how would I best go about creating a thread pool for Read() that is started when the connection is confirmed. If std::thread's are destroyed on the return, and I have no other loop to hold the thread alive, then another solution is required. This would be easier in C#, but it's not an option with the SDK provided.

Comment: So don't destroy them. Make them class members. Which, also, conveniently eliminates the need for any pointer to them.

Comment: confirmed
Socket.public: void StartReadThread() { reader = std::thread(&Socket::Read, this); }
appears to solve the problem. Update your Answer and I can mark as valid.

Comment: Correction, that just moved the line at which it crashes. Do you have a source snippet I can look at to learn how to make a thread a class member?

Comment: The same way you make anything else a class member. You already have member named `sock`, `onConnect`, and `onDisconnect`. Just add a `std::thread` class member, instead of having a class member that's a pointer to a `std::thread`.